# Windows 10 PC with an i5-7600 doesn't run at 3GHz anymore, but at around 1.60GHz, even while gaming/video editing

Tags: windows-10, cpu, motherboard, issue-tracking

This is a serious problem, because all the games/software I use perform really badly now. I've had this issue since yesterday and I've never encountered anything like this before. I know that the CPU will adjust the clock speed automatically, but, as  I said in the title, this occurs even while playing triple A titles like FarCry 5 etc or editing videos.

My PC Specs:

CPU: i5-7600
RAM: 16gb (2x8gb) DDR4
GPU: GTX 970 4gb
Motherboard: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.  H110M-S2-CF

My PC was built by a specialist (from parts)
What is the reason for this? Maybe the coolers failed (I don't know)?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: could you post a screenshot of the Task Manager > Performance tab ??

Comment: @Emiley Of course, I actually made it, but I forgot to add it.

Comment: did you install anything recently ..drivers softwares updates ??? try to uninstall them and check.
Any changes to BIOS ?? Try updating the BIOS as well.

Comment: @Emiley No, I didn't. They may, however be outdated, because FarCry 5 told me that I need to update them for better performance.

Comment: screenshot loading .....

Comment: @Emiley If the screenshot isn't working I can upload it to Mediafire and I'll give a link

Comment: Run the [Intel Processor Diagnostic Tool](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/19792/Intel-Processor-Diagnostic-Tool) if there is a problem with it changing speeds appropriately it will tell you. If it comes back fine then the problem is not what you describe. What I see is a CPU under constant load. That is probably the problem. What is causing a constant 50% load? Look in the details tab.

Comment: @Appleodity I ran the tool and no errors were detected. What should I do? I've also noticed that sometimes I DON'T get the problem after restarting the PC, but sometimes when I launch it (after shutting down), it appears again...

Comment: Look on the details tab and identify what is taking 50% of the CPU constantly.

Comment: @Appleoddity After some time, I've noticed that my CPU doesn't run on lonq frequencies anymore and the usage percentage is now normal. It seems like the Intel application was the solution. Is it possible to make Your comment become an answer?